# Link .ll files generated by compiling .cu file with clang

Tags: cuda, clang, llvm

I am compiling the following code using clang with:
`clang++ -std=c++11 -emit-llvm -c -S $1 --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_30`. This generates `vectoradd-cuda-nvptx64-nvidia-cuda-sm_30.ll` and `vectoradd.ll` files. The goal to run some LLVM analysis passes on the kernel, which would possibly instrument it. So i would like to link the post-analysis IR to an executable but i am not sure how. When i try to link the .ll files with `llvm-link` i am getting the error `Linking globals named '_Z9vectoraddPiS_S_i': symbol multiply defined!`. I am not really sure how to achieve this, so any help is appreciated.

```
#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK 512

__global__ void vectoradd(int *A, int *B, int *C, int N) {
  int gi = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  if ( gi < N) {
    C[gi] = A[gi] + B[gi];
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int N = 10000, *d_A, *d_B, *d_C;

  /// allocate host memory
  std::vector<int> A(N);
  std::vector<int> B(N);
  std::vector<int> C(N);

  /// allocate device memory
  cudaMalloc((void **) &d_A, N * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void **) &d_B, N * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void **) &d_C, N * sizeof(int));

  /// populate host data
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    A[i] = i; B[i] = i;
  }

  /// copy to device
  cudaMemcpy(d_A, &A[0], N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_B, &B[0], N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  dim3 block(THREADS_PER_BLOCK, 1, 1);
  dim3 grid((N + THREADS_PER_BLOCK - 1) / THREADS_PER_BLOCK, 1, 1);

  vectoradd<<<grid,block>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, N);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  cudaMemcpy(&C[0], d_C, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The CUDA compilation trajectory in Clang is rather [complicated](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html#compilation-models) (as it is in the NVIDIA toolchain) and what you are trying to do cannot work. The LLVM IR from each branch of the compilation process must remain separate until directly linkable objects are available. As a result, there are many intermediate steps which you will need to perform manually.

LLVM IR code for the GPU must be compiled firstly to PTX code, and then assembled to a binary payload which can be linked against host object files.

So in your example, you first do something like:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -emit-llvm -c -S test.cu --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_52
```

which emits two llvm IR files `test-cuda-nvptx64-nvidia-cuda-sm_52.ll` and `test.ll`. The GPU code then needs to be compiled to PTX (see more about the nvptx backend [here](https://llvm.org/docs/NVPTXUsage.html)):

```
llc -mcpu=sm_52 test-cuda-nvptx64-nvidia-cuda-sm_52.ll -o test.ptx
```

Now the PTX code can be assembled into an ELF file which can later be linked by nvcc (or the host linker with an couple of additional steps) in the normal way:

```
ptxas --gpu-name=sm_52 test.ptx -o test.ptx.o
fatbinary --cuda -64 --create test.fatbin --image=profile=sm_52,file=test.ptx.o
```

For the host code you do something like

```
llc test.ll
clang -m64 -c test.s
```

to produce assembler output from the LLVM IR and then assemble that to an object file.

Now with a fatbin file containing CUDA the compiled code, and an object file containing the compiled host code, you can perform linkage. I have not been able to test linking a host object file with a fatbinary using clang, that is something you will need to work out yourself.  It will be instructive to study both the verbose output of clang during a CUDA compilation call, and also the nvcc documentation to get a better feel for how the device code build system works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what about the test.ll file of your example? How is that linked?

Comment: Using llc and then an assembler. I assumed you already knew how to do that. You do understand that `llvm-link` is a tool for joining multiple IR files into a single IR file, and not for compiling and linking code?

Comment: Yes. I didn't imply llvm-link _has_ to be used or something. I am just not sure how to link the result of using llc on test.ll and test.ptx.o. I would appreciate a working example that demonstrates this. Thank you for the effort so far. Really appreciated.

Comment: Just embedding GPU-side fatbinary in the host .o will not be sufficient. Compiler generates fair amount of glue to inform CUDA runtime about existence of device-side binary and how to match host-side things with their device-side counterparts. You could try re-running running host-only compilation and manually pass the blob via `-fcuda-include-gpubinary manually-created.fatbin`, but things are likely to break if things in the fatbin don't quite match what the host wants to see.