# How to generate binary executable from linked LLVM IR of CUDA files?

Tags: cuda, clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

I am writing an LLVM pass to analyze the LLVM IR of CUDA files generated using clang. However, I needed to analyze both the CPU and GPU function calls. Hence, I linked two IR files using llvm-link and created a new LLVM IR file. However, I cannot generate a binary executable upon analyzing the linked IR using the opt tool. I get the following error when I try to generate a binary executable using clang.

```
'sm_35' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'+ptx75' is not a recognized feature for this target (ignoring feature)
'+sm_35' is not a recognized feature for this target (ignoring feature)
'sm_35' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'sm_35' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'+ptx75' is not a recognized feature for this target (ignoring feature)
'+sm_35' is not a recognized feature for this target (ignoring feature)
'sm_35' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
fatal error: error in backend: 64-bit code requested on a subtarget that doesn't support it!
clang-14: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 14.0.6 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git f28c006a5895fc0e329fe15fead81e37457cb1d1)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Can someone help me with it?

I tried to run my pass using Clang also, but it runs the pass before the host-side and device-side code even links. Hence, my analysis throws an error. I am trying to register the pass in the Clang pipeline now, so that I can run it using Clang without dumping intermediate representations.

P.S.
I am using the following command to generate the binary executable:

```
./bin/clang++ -I ../../../../common/ -flegacy-pass-manager  <linked_llvm_ir>.ll -L /usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart_static -ldl -lrt -pthread -std=c++14 -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone
```

Comment: What you are trying to do isn’t possible. The Clang compilation paths for GPU and host code are fundamentally separate and can’t be combined as you are trying to do

Comment: So, is there any way to run my passes on the given CUDA IRs and get an transformed executable ? Is it possible to run my analysis on the IR in the clang pipeline ? so that it will get a full view of the translation unit ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58799646/681865 might help, but I am still skeptical it will work properly with the runtime API. With the driver API you can load your GPU payload at runtime and it will work.